# Foreground and Background, which apps where?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode6, development-environment

Is it possible to formulate an application for iOS platform which records those applications that are currently running in background and those which are in the foreground and then accordingly make a log of it. Appreciate any ideas?

Eg. App1 app2 app3 are running in background whereas app4 is running in foreground. Any way, via which we can get a notification or an entirely different application stating that background consists of: app 1,2,3 and foreground consists of app 4?

Comment: is my answer clear or do you need further explanation?

Answer (score 1):

sorry to disappoint you, but this is not possible on iOS. This is for two reasons:

1) An app doesn't have access to this information in the first place because apps on iOS are running in a *sandboxed* environment. There is no global point in the OS where an app A could come an ask for information about app B.

2) Executing code in the background is very tricky on iOS and Apple only allows it in certain situations (e.g. location updates, playing audio or background fetches). If you want an app to constantly log a certain information, you'll have to think of a way to do so by accepting Apple's limitations in that matter.